# Access private methods variables in another java class in same package.

Tags: java

I am new to java. Can anyone please tell me best way to access private method variables in another class. Thank u

Comment: Their private for a reason, look for the getter method of the variable

Comment: Private methods are private for a reason, change the visibility of those methods (if you can) in order to access them.

Answer (score 2):

Private variables are private for a reason- you're not supposed to be able to access them directly. Many classes do have getter methods though which allow you to access private variables but not change them. If you need to access private variables in your program, you need to rethink your design.

Comment: Well, except for maybe a test from Junit